# Scrolling List using Android View Client(DTmilano)

Tags: android, androidviewclient

I am looking forward to scroll a list with the help of Android view client(dtmilano) .The list has 109 elements and only 10 are visible. So i need to scroll down and again perform  vc.dump .
Kindly guide with a sample python code to perform scroll down operation.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [MonkeyDevice.drag()](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/MonkeyDevice.html#drag) and your script would look something like this

```
list = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise(someid)
(x, y, w, h) = list.getPositionAndSize()
start = (int(x+w/2.0), y+h)
end = (int(x+w/2.0), y)
# scroll 5 times
for i in range(5):
    vc.device.drag(start, end, 1.0, 10)
```

Comment: Hi Diego ,
Thank you for the guidance.However i am not able to drag the window vertically with the above code.
I am using Emulator with GoogleAPI 10,resolution is w=768 and h=1280. The list which i want to scroll has the below dimensions ,
x=0,y=250,w=768,h=1030.
Further , i am able to drag the list vertically with device.drag((380,1000),(380,10),0.10,10). I wish to set these  values at run time based on the list dimensions.
Thank you.

Comment: Also what was happening earlier,the drag method was clicking the element instead of dragging.I tried to extend device class to override_onLongClick_method,here is the sample code:
class TestDevice(MonkeyRunner):
    def __new__(self):
        return MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(30,deviceId='emulator-5554') 
    def __init__(self):
        MonkeyDevice.__init__(self)
 def takeSnapshot(self):
  a=5
  return a

However without implementing this , the drag method started working as desired .Is it an issue or there was something wrong with emulator as i again created an emulator and that worked.

Comment: Hi Diego,Yes it worked with slight modification.Here is the modified parameters,

start = (int(x+w/2.0), y+h-250)
end = (int(x+w/2.0), y-250)
Thank you Sir for the guidance.